# Hypothetical Windows virus in WINE

Tags: wine

I am running Ubuntu with WINE on it for running some Windows program like a pdf reader.

These programs  can clearly access my Linux docs, and change them. I know that Linux system files are out of bounds for viruses. However I wonder whether a virus would be able to change, corrupt, delete, snoop, ...,  my personal files, in the same way that legit programs can change them.

Or what is blocking a hypothetical WINE virus from causing havoc on the Linux installation? After all, a virus is just a program.

Comment: "this virus" Do you currently have a specific virus? Then name it. Or edit your question so that we know it's a hypothetical one.

Comment: @JanDoggen done.

Answer (score 2):

In short, malware could harm your system in the case of files it has access to on the permissions level.  For running particularly untrusted code in wine, it is best practice to use a method of sandboxing/containment such as lxc or chroot provide.

Others are right to suggest you're not likely to encounter much Windows malware that will still be effective in wine, but it's by no means impossible (which is one of a few reasons the folks at WineHQ advise against ever running wine as root.

If you're running pirated content in particular, or anything questionable for that matter, it's probably worth at least setting up a chroot'ed environment or lxc.  If you don't, however, I probably won't have a chance to rub it in your face.

Answer (score -1):

Someone could write a virus which can operate on WINE, but a couple things needed for consideration:

WINE is not a full Windows operating system. In essence it provides a framework for running OS specific applications on another OS. With this limited functionality it would be more difficult to write a virus which could manipulate enough using the tools available.

There is an added problem for such a virus. Most are written with a single OS in mind. In order for a WINE virus to damage your host it would need to function in both this restricted Windows like environment and whatever flavor of Linux you happen to be running at the time.

For a sample of tested viruses and how well they functioned on WINE you can have a look in the archive on [linux.com](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/42031)

Comment: And why can my pdf tool (Foxit) operate (change, write) on my Linux files? Couldn't a virus be like this program, but malicious, and instead of doing what I told it, just delete my files, or scramble them? It won't damage the host, that's clear, but my docs wouldn't be protected.

Comment: @QuoraFeans | In theory it could, but copying a file to your system and executing a program are different things. Linux is rather good like this in that permissions are rather restricted as to what applications are allowed to do if and when they are allowed access onto the system.

Comment: So, it's safe from the point of view that it won't be able to run itself in the Linux installation (as a worm, or a keylogger, for example); but not safe in the sense that it could open my docs, and, transform them in some form of scrambled text? (although in the last case, I can be still secure if it doesn't have a internet connection, so it can not send my docs somewhere).

Comment: @QuoraFeans | I would never say someone can't produce code to run such a malware configuration, but I am unaware of any which exists, so you are as secure as you are going to get.